# When one of the two objects of a verb is a reflexive pronoun

Tags: objects, reflexive-pronouns, indirect-objects, intensive-prounouns

We say 'pass me the salt' and 'pass the salt to me'.
We also say 'I found the right car for me'.

But which of the following sentences are correct?

> I found the right car for **myself**.
> I found **myself** the right car.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a car that suits me:

> I have found myself <sup>reflexive</sup> the right car.
>   I have found the right car for me.    [colloquial]
>   I found me <sup>reflexive</sup> a car.     [regional, nonstandard]

I found it all on my own, unassisted:

> I have found the right car myself.
>   I have found the right car for myself.
>   I, myself, have found the right car.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. Consider these expanded versions:

- Rather than relying on anyone's help, I found the right car for myself.
- After looking high and low, I found myself the right car.

Answer (score 0):

> I found the right car for **myself**

is understandable to mean

> I found the right car for **me**

which is the correct sentence to use

> I found **myself** the right car

could be interpreted to mean either

> I found the right car **for me**
>   I found the right car **myself**

the latter meaning you had **no help** in choosing the car

Comment: So "I found the right car for myself'' is grammatically correct?

Comment: It's understandable, I've heard it used, strictly speaking it's not correct **me** should be used. Do you say "yes, it's me!" or "yes, it's I!"? It's kind of the same thing ("yes, it's I" is correct), so no it's not **strictly** grammatically correct, but people use it

Comment: Your analysis seems to be saying that [*I found the answer for myself*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22found+the+answer+for+myself%22) should always imply that of multiple potential answers, the one ***I*** found was the one most appropriate one for me. But glancing at some of the claimed 136 results in that link, it seems many if not most of them carry the sense that I found (the one and only) answer *alone, without help from others*.

Comment: "I ... for myself" is correct, as is "He ... for himself", but 'I' am unique, so the reflexive isn't required and "I ... for me" is acceptable.  "He ... for him" implies that two different males are involved.

Answer (score 0):

"I found the right car for me" 
is saying
"I found the right car [for my unique set of needs]"

Your proposed "I found myself the right car" is essentially equivalent to this.

Your other proposed construction, "I found the right car for myself," would typically be used to say that you accomplished the task by yourself, and would *not* imply that the "right car" was right because it fit your unique needs.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct.
"I found the right car ***for myself***."

Means the car which suits MAXIMUM requirements of mine as a person. ***As if custom- made for me***. If I am 6'2" I would need a special car, for example.

[2]
I found ***myself*** the right car.

I found it ***by my personal efforts***, without the help of dealers selling pr- used cars say.

Like my first job as if, I approached employers personally and got myself picked up- without seeking any assistance from an Employment agency may be.

Answer (score 0):

- I found the right car for myself (me)

This sentence means,  with the help of some others or you ,all by yourself, got the the car you we're in the look out for.

- I found myself the right car.

Here ' myself ' is more of an emphatic pronoun as in a sentence— I myself did it. You found out the car yourself; the credit is all yours!

Actually ' _self' is not all needed in the first example, but it's a kind of colloquialism . It may even run the risk of transmitting a sense of humorous exclusivity. In that sense use of 'myself ' is fit and proper in the 2nd. example.

We shouldn't, by the way, use the expression reflexive pronoun for the first example and grudgingly use reflexive for the second.